# sharepoint 2010 upload file to document library using jquery

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-foundation, jquery

Hi all using jquery i want to upload file to solution gallery.

so is that possible to upload file in solution gallery using jquery.

how?

another thing is it possible to upload file in document library using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that copy file from one document library to other using jquery

```
         $(document).ready(function () {     

      function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {

             var draggable = $(ui.draggable);     

        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();   
          var web = context.get_web();   
          var lists = web.get_lists(); 
            var _destinationlib = lists.getByTitle("My Documents");   
          context.load(web);       
      context.load(_destinationlib);   

          var currentLib = lists.getByTitle("Excel Library");  
          var currentItem = currentLib.getItemById(44);             
          context.load(currentItem);   
           var File = currentItem.get_file();   
          context.load(File);        
context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {if (File != null) {var _destinationlibUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + _destinationlib.get_title() + '/' + File.get_name();                        
 File.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl,true);                                                   
context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {},function (sender, args) {SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error copying file', false);                                    SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);                                  showError(args.get_message());                              });                         }                   },                  function (sender, args) {                       alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());                    }                 );             }         });
```