# How to read image file from a URL and save the image in image library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, jquery, asp.net, url, inputformtextbox

I have a form, and that form has a field for a Picture and a Thumbnail which are currently Single Text fields. What I would like to do is when people input a URL on those fields, I would like to get the image of that URL and save it onto a SharePoint Picture Library.

I can find the value of the fields by using jquery, but I am wondering how can I find them on the back end.

According to this site: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/50deca94-71b4-4081-9dc6-81fc7e86886f/how-to-read-image-file-from-a-url-and-save-the-image-in-image-library-in-sharepoint-2010

It looks like I need this to get the image in the SharePoint Library

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
    SPFolder oFolder = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["TargetWebSite"].GetFolder("TargetDocumentLibrary");
    SPFileCollection spFileCollection = oFolder.Files;
    string targetFileUrl = spFileCollection.Folder.Url + "/" + "cust.png";
    spFileCollection.Add(targetFileUrl,imageBytes, true); 
}
```

My issue is how do I get the url, is it okay if I just use jquery, or how do I tell this I have the url so it can save it to the appropriate folder.

So I was able to download an image using this code:

```
string localFilename = @"c:\tofile.jpg";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile("http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2013/03/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1115-am.jpg", localFilename);
        }
```

but how would I go about it and

1. Save it to a sharepoint picture library, something like this:  SPList mylist=objWeb.Lists["Shared"];.
2. I will need to use ajax to pass my parameter? such as instead of a hardcode url, a url that somebody inputs in a field.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your 'form'? a list item?

Comment: Yes it is a list item. And I want to modify the uploading an image. I want to be able to put any url with an image..ex http://blog.heartland.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Google.jpg and when I either put the link on the input field or when I submit it, it will grab the image and save it into my Picture Library. Does it make sense?

Comment: Why not use `Event Receiver` instead of jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code for file upload:

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPList docLibrary = web.Lists["Documents"];
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            Stream fStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

                            SPFile file = web.Files.Add(web.Url.ToString() + "/" + docLibrary.Title.ToString() + "/" + FileUpload1.FileName, fStream, true);
                            file.Update();
                            docLibrary.Update();

                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in the following URL to upload pictures to DocLib using jquery.

[sharepoint 2010 upload file to document library using jquery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38529/sharepoint-2010-upload-file-to-document-library-using-jquery)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Add the details from the link to your post with the link as source. This way, the answer will still be helpful if the link breaks